# Is the Linux install procedure the same on a VM as it is on a physical machine?

Tags: linux, installation, virtual-machine

I'm a Windows user, but have been considering a switch to Linux.

My aim is to make this transition as smooth as possible, so to that end, I've been thinking of creating a Virtual Machine and run a Linux distribution on it.

Would this be the same as installing Linux on a physical machine? Would it provide the same experience?  Would I still need to install all drivers (etc.) that I would normally do, or would it somehow be different when run as a Virtual Machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Question used to start "**Best way to start using Linux**" but has since been edited out, now my answer is a little superfluous but still relevant.]

You could start by using the programs available in Linux to see if you like them, many have Windows & Mac versions too. Like LibreOffice, OpenOffice, GIMP, Firefox, Chromium, Thunderbird, Pidgin, VLC, Transmission?

If you can use those, trying out a few different live ISO's (CD/DVD/USB) for a few hours or days would be good to see if they even run on your computer, and if you like them. Many can run "persistent" on a USB to save changes too. There are **lots** of them available:  Debian (Stable version should be more... stable, but older), Ubuntu, ***Linux Mint***, CrunchBang, Puppy Linux, Fedora, OpenSUSE... at least a hundred others too.

Most with multiple different desktop environments available too like XFCE, gnome shell, Cinnamon, Mate, LXDE, K, Unity...)

see http://www.distrowatch.com for good overviews & search capability. And watch some videos of them in action on youtube (there were some videos of an Australian guy who has his mom test a *bunch* of different OS's that are interesting & fun).

Running in a virtual machine would give the feel, but not really test the hardware compatibility. I've used iso's in VirtualBox that completely fail to boot when run "for real." Some like Linux Mint & Ubuntu will usually "just work" but sometimes they need special "boot parameters" to work too... usually have to try & see, then search for any problems that come up.

Most of the "drivers" are built into the kernel, there are some proprietary video drivers that may be (optionally) available. Ubuntu and Mint (at least) have a "Driver Manager" type program that can find some easily.

Comment: I've already been using almost exclusively programs that are OS and available for Linux so in this regards the change won't be dramatic. Installing drivers seems like the bigger issue for me, hence why I wanted to know if the VM would bring the "real experience". It seems like I'll install it as a separate OS.

Comment: Most of the "drivers" are built into the kernel, there are some proprietary video drivers that may be (optionally) available. But if one distro/iso doesn't boot, try a different desktop version of it, or just a different distro.

Comment: If You worry about hardware compatibility, try Live version of distro.

Comment: @kat you dont play any game? I mean professional games such as Call of or Watch dogs (which are not available in linux) ? The only reason Im not leaving windows is these games ............

Comment: @TechLife Not enough games on Steam? Or PlayOnLinux? They don't run in a windows in VirtualBox?

Comment: No, I don't play any games. Guess, I'm a square. I once tried Ubuntu, but couldn't find a driver for my video card, so I gave up on it. But now I'm looking into Linux once more and this time I'm determined to make the switch - since most of the software I already use has a Linux version.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual Machines have their own devices, i.e. They virtualize your devices to their own type. This means that you may not have to install the drivers.
Also as I know VmWare Workstation has something called `Guest Additions` Which is installed on the OS once it has completed installing the OS on virtual machine. This little program has the drivers needed to use the virtual devices made by VMware itself.
So the answer is NO, You dont have to install all the drivers on the virtual machine compared to physical machine, neither for virtual windows nor linux installation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's virtualization system is called Hyper-V and is included in Windows Server. There is comprehensive information for Linux under Hyper-V located at [Linux and FreeBSD Virtual Machines on Hyper-V](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/Supported-Linux-and-FreeBSD-virtual-machines-for-Hyper-V-on-Windows). Also, see [Ubuntu 14.04 in a Generation 2 VM](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220204954/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2014/06/09/ubuntu-14-04-in-a-generation-2-vm.aspx) on Ben Armstrong’s Virtualization Blog.

For a non-"Windows Server" OS a couple of your other virtualization options are [Windows Virtual PC](https://web.archive.org/web/20210126194612/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) and [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

For the most part this will be the same experience you would otherwise have, although some of the driver behavior may be a little different due to the virtualization.